# Visual Studio 2017 suddenly stopped compiling typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

This was working until about two hours ago and nothing I've tried (from clean build to restarting my computer) has worked.

Basically I am changing typescript but visual studio is still running the old typescript I had written ages ago.

main-server.js is NOT changing which it used to and looking ta the javascript it looks like it's running some of the old code I had (looking up an old webapi service url).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: are you sure you have run `tns run android/ios`? if the cli isnt using livesync, it wont recompile

Comment: are you using the [spa templates](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)?  [if so try](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/#invoking-webpack-manually) `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the typescript file is included in your tsconfig.json so it gets compiled

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html